# Writing multi-dimensional struct values to file in C

Tags: c, struct, printf

I'm trying to figure out how to write the values of a struct that encompasses another struct to a file. Here's the code I'm working with:

```
/*header1.h*/
typedef struct _struct1 {
    double valid;
    double id;
    double timestamp;
}STRUCT1;

/*header2.h*/
#define HEADDER 1
#define TOFILE 1

typedef struct _struct2 {
     STRUCT1 track[10];
}STRUCT2;

/* main.c */
findData (double timestamp)
{
     int i;
     STRUCT2 inData;

     for(i=0; i<6; i++)
     {
         inData.track[i].valid     = 1.0;
         inData.track[i].id        = 2.0;
         inData.track[i].timestamp = 1234.5;
     }

     dataRouter(TOFILE, &inData, sizeof(STRUCT2), (void *)HEADDER);
}

/*dataRouter.c*/

void dataRouter( int type, void *data, int size, void *args)
{
     switch (type)
     {
          case TOFILE:  sendFile(data, size, (int *) args); break;
     }
}

void sendFile (void *data, int size, int args)
{
     switch (args)
     {
          case 1:
               head = "idx1";
               break;
     }

 //somehow print all the values for track[] 
 //"head, track[i].valid, track[i].id, track[i].timestamp" 

}
```

I'm confused on how to turn "void *data" which is "&data" into a variable or data structure that could be iterated through using a for loop and printed to a file.

note: I'm working in an embedded environment with limited space for libraries so I'm trying to work with the standard C libraries.

Any advice or references would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Cast it t0 char* and iterate

Answer (score 0):

If all `sendFile` needs to do is write what `data` points to into a file, just pass the pointer and size to `write`:

```
write(fd, data, size);
```

You'll perform a similar operation to read back from disk.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my issue by performing

```
data->track.value
```

Thank's everyone for your response.